# Algorithm to check consecutive letters in a QWERTY keyboard

Tags: java, algorithm, passwords

I need to write an algorithm in Java to validate a password field.
Between all the basic controls (minimum length, lunghezza massima, alphanumeric...) I gotta check that the password is not composed of characters in sequence from the keyboard (eg ***QWERTY, YTREWQ, ASDFGH***, etc.). 
The minimum password length is 8 characters.  Password is disqualified after 4 digits
I cannot create a "dictionary-table" in my DB with the "forbidden" strings, any tip about an existing algorithm or if there's a library already doing a check like this?

Comment: How many `QWERTY` letters in succession disqualifies a password?  Have you tried anything on your own yet?

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen, thanks for your reply. Yes, I did like a demo thing very basic using an List to check if the password is contained. Of course this solution is not solid because I would need to add all this possible "words" to the List. Password is disqualified after 4 digits.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  You should clarify what you are asking if you want to get help here.

Comment: Why can you not create a dictionary with the forbidden substrings, there should be only around 40 (80 when reverse is forbidden too)?

Comment: Hi@SaiBot, yes reverse is forbidden too. I think it's more than 40/80 forbidden words if you consider also numbers and special chars.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... One thing comes to my mind.

You can try to construct a matrix of letters:

```
-----------------------
| q  w  e  r  t  y  ... 
| a  s  d  f  g  h  ... etc.
| z  x  c  v  b  n  ... 
-----------------------
```

Give each letter an index. For instance, 'q' has [1,1], 'w' has [2, 1], 'v' has [4,3] and so on.

Now, given a String, find the distance between each letter and sum them.

Example: 
Given a string "sdgh":

```
s-d, distance is 1
d-g, distance is 2
g-h, distance is 1

Total distance is: 4
```

Now you have a ratio of 4/4. (Four letters, the total distance is four). 
Is that ok with your security requirements? Answer this question and you're done.

Comment: Hi @Pavel,  thats a good tip. But what if the password starts with 1QAZ? Technically the horizontal distance is ok, but not the vertical. Shoud i check the total distance in both directions?

Comment: Most keyboards don't have a rectangular layout, but a more complicated one where 'z' is midway below 'a' and 's'; thus if you want to compute the vertical distance it is messier - and I assume you don't want 'zse4xdr5'. Additionally keyboards differ in different countries - on a German keyboard I believe 'y' is lower-left instead of 'z'.

Comment: @aramone, you should check both horizontal and vertical distance. q and a - distance is still 1. q and s - this is a tricky case. You can consider the distance to be 2, or 1, as you wish.

Comment: Plus, you can improve the algorithm and add a distance point at each vertical shift, if you want. So that 'cft6yhn' will give the distance of 12.

Comment: thanks for all your tips. I'm coding right now a first solution, i'll keep you posted about!

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my solution, it seems to work quite well for horizontal check. If distance is > 4 it means the password is not valid. Any tip to improve it? I know it's a bit hard-coded but at the moment i can pass on it.

```
    @Test
public void runCheckDigit() {

    checkdigit("cnqwerty13");

}

public void checkdigit(String password) {

    int x = 4;
    int y = 10;

    String[][] keyboard = new String[x][y];


    // first row
    keyboard[0][0] = "1";
    keyboard[0][1] = "2";
    keyboard[0][2] = "3";
    keyboard[0][3] = "4";
    keyboard[0][4] = "5";
    keyboard[0][5] = "6";
    keyboard[0][6] = "7";
    keyboard[0][7] = "8";
    keyboard[0][8] = "9";
    keyboard[0][9] = "0";

    // second row
    keyboard[1][0] = "q";
    keyboard[1][1] = "w";
    keyboard[1][2] = "e";
    keyboard[1][3] = "r";
    keyboard[1][4] = "t";
    keyboard[1][5] = "y";
    keyboard[1][6] = "u";
    keyboard[1][7] = "i";
    keyboard[1][8] = "o";
    keyboard[1][9] = "p";
    // TERZA RIGA
    keyboard[2][0] = "a";
    keyboard[2][1] = "s";
    keyboard[2][2] = "d";
    keyboard[2][3] = "f";
    keyboard[2][4] = "g";
    keyboard[2][5] = "h";
    keyboard[2][6] = "j";
    keyboard[2][7] = "k";
    keyboard[2][8] = "l";
    keyboard[2][9] = "ò";
    // third row
    keyboard[3][0] = "z";
    keyboard[3][1] = "x";
    keyboard[3][2] = "c";
    keyboard[3][3] = "v";
    keyboard[3][4] = "b";
    keyboard[3][5] = "n";
    keyboard[3][6] = "m";
    keyboard[3][7] = ",";
    keyboard[3][8] = ".";
    keyboard[3][9] = "-";

    printMatrix(keyboard, x, y);

    List<Coordinata> cList = new ArrayList<Coordinata>();

    for (int i = 0, n = password.length(); i < n; i++) {
        char s = password.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        cList.add(getCoordinate(s, keyboard));
    }
    int distanza = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cList.size()-1; i++) {
        distanza = distanza + distanceElement(cList.get(i), cList.get(i + 1));
    }

    System.out.println("distanza : " + distanza);
}


private static Coordinata getCoordinate(char s, String[][] keyboard) {
    Coordinata c = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < keyboard[0].length; ++j) {
            if (keyboard[i][j].equals(Character.toString(s))) {
                // Found the correct i,j 
                return c = new Coordinata(i, j, Character.toString(s));
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}

private static int distanceElement(Coordinata c1, Coordinata c2) {
    int distance = 0;       
    distance = Math.abs(c2.getX() - c1.getX()) + Math.abs(c2.getY() - c1.getY());
    System.out.println("Distance: " + c1.getLettera() + "->" + c2.getLettera() + " = " + distance);     
    return distance;
}

private static void printMatrix(String[][] matrix, int matrixRow, int matrixCol) {
    System.out.println("Matrix is : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixCol; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you using a Map<Character, Coordinata> to look up an index of a character in O(1) time instead of looping through array. Use it instead of 'keyboard' array.